# ownership of files that are written by the docker container to mounted volume

Tags: linux, docker

I'm using non-root user on a secured env to run stock DB docker container (elasticsearch). Of course - I want the data to be mounted so I won't lose it when the container is destroyed.

The problem is that this container writes to that volume with root ownership, and then the host doesn't have permissions to move/rm them.

I know that most docker images use root user from inside, but how can I control the file ownership of the hosting machine?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a data container `docker create -v  /usr/share/elasticsearch/data --name esdata elasticsearch /bin/true`, then use it in your container `docker run -d --volumes-from esdata --name some-elasticsearch elasticsearch`.

This is a prefer data pattern for docker, you can find out more in [this](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) docker page.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question use "docker run --user '$(id -u)' ..." it will run program within container with current user id, then you might have the same question as I did.

I answered it in some way I hope it might be useful.
[Docker with '--user' can not write to volume with different ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067160/docker-with-user-can-not-write-to-volume-with-different-ownership/33067677#33067677)