# Docker with '--user' can not write to volume with different ownership

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I've played a lot with any rights combinations to make docker to work, but... at first my environment:

Ubuntu linux 15.04 and Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef.

I have a directory '/test/dockervolume' and two users user1 and user2 in a group users

```
chown user1.users /test/dockervolume
chmod 775 /test/dockervolume
ls -la
drwxrwxr-x  2 user1 users 4096 Oct 11 11:57 dockervolume
```

Either user1 and user2 can write delete files in this directory.
I use standard docker ubuntu:15.04 image. user1 has id 1000 and user2 has id 1002.

I run docker with next command:

```
docker run -it --volume=/test/dcokervolume:/tmp/job_output --user=1000 --workdir=/tmp/job_output ubuntu:15.04
```

Within docker I just do simple 'touch test' and it works for user1 with id 1000. When I run docker with --user 1002 I can't write to that directory:

```
I have no name!@6c5e03f4b3a3:/tmp/job_output$ touch test2
touch: cannot touch 'test2': Permission denied
I have no name!@6c5e03f4b3a3:/tmp/job_output$
```

Just to be clear both users can write to that directory if not in docker.

So my question is this behavior by docker design or it is a bug or I missed something in the manual?

Comment: Ah, you helped me to understand that :) Within docker container I can have id=1002 but the group did not change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

docker's --user parameter changes just id not a group id within a docker. So, within a docker I have:

```
id
uid=1002 gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

and it is not like in original system where I have groups=1000(users)

So, one workaround might be mapping passwd and group files into a docker.

```
-v /etc/docker/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/docker/group:/etc/group:ro
```

The other idea is to map a tmp directory owned by running --user and when docker's work is complete copy files to a final location

```
 TMPFILE=`mktemp`; docker run -v $TMPFILE:/working_dir/ --user=$(id -u); cp $TMPDIR $NEWDIR
```

This discussion [Understanding user file ownership in docker: how to avoid changing permissions of linked volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500270/understanding-user-file-ownership-in-docker-how-to-avoid-changing-permissions-o/26514736#26514736) brings some light to my question.

Answer (score 1):

For both correct uid **and** gid mapping try: `docker run --user=$(id -u):$(id -g)`

Comment: And now for a one-line command mapping all the user's groups (id -G) with --group-add!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid use another use, because the UID is different and you can't sure about the user name. You can use root without problem inside container.

Comment: If you have part of real system connected into docker with --volume then I would suggest avoid to use root at all, because all created files will be owned by root

Comment: But you can use root inside container without problem. The process inside container don't access outside of container.

Comment: The root user inside the container is your host root user, with heavy limitations/restrictions, but still the root user. It's better to avoid using root. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#linux-kernel-capabilities